# Bitwise shifting to the right question in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a number : 13 for example
In binary its : 1101

I want to shift every bit once to the right, and move the last bit to the beginning and so on :

`1101 shift once to the right = 1110, shift again= 0111, and again = 1011`

I thought `>>` was gonna help me but this just moves every bit to the right and discards the last.

The result I get from `1101 >> 1` is `0110`, but the desired output is `1110`

Comment: What you are looking for is called rotation. See code example here: https://gist.github.com/cincodenada/6557582

Comment: is there something simpler?

Comment: You should define a little more carefully how many bits you with to rotate. In the example above, you rotated 4 bits, meaning 1101 -> 1110. What about 0101? should it be 1010 or 110?

Comment: 0101 would be 1010

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called rotation.

One implementation would be:

```
def rotate_right(num, length):
    return (num >> 1 ) | (num % 2 << (length - 1))
```

Comment: Have you learned methods yet? this function takes a number `num` and the desired length `length` and shifts the number one time to the right, and them "pop"s the last bit (which is the parity bit) to the top. You can call it with `rotate_right(13,4)` to see the result in your example.